# Error when importing into a spark dataframe a mssql table named as an integer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in MSSQL named as dbo.1table and I need to convert it into a dataframe and later on save it as an avro file but I can't even load it as dataframe.

I tested my code with tables named with characters a-z and it works, I tried to convert the table name "toString()" and nothing has worked so far.
I expect to have a dataframe and then save it as an avro file.
Instead I have the folloiwng error:

```
val DFDimAccountOperator = spark.read.format("jdbc")
   .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
   .option("url", connection)
   .option("dbtable", "dbo.1table")
   .option("user", userId)
   .option("password", pwd).load() 
   DFDimAccountOperator.write.format("avro").save("conversionTypes/testinAVro13")

Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '.1'.    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1621)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:592)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:522)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2935)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:444)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:61)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
   at com.aon.ukbi.TomsExample$.runJdbcDatasetExample(TomsExample.scala:27)
   at com.aon.ukbi.TomsExample$.main(TomsExample.scala:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **connection**

For making a connection between MSSQL and Spark you need to add [sqljdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0) jar into $SPARK_HOME/jars location and restart your spark-shell and paste these line into Spark Shell.

```
scala> val DFDimAccountOperator = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")   .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxx.xxx:1433;database=xx;user=xxxxxx;password=xxxxxx") .option("dbtable", "xxxxxx").load()
```

> **Restart and Re-run Code(replace XXXX with appropiate value)**

after this, you can write your data frame whichever format you want.

```
DFDimAccountOperator.write.format("avro").save("conversionTypes/testinAVro13")
```

Hope this helps you let me know if you have further queries related to this if its solve your purpose accept the answer HAppy HAdooop

Comment: I still have the same error: Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '1'.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262). The code will work if the table doesn't start with an integer.

Comment: @Isamu just replace option("dbtable", "xxxxxx") with  this code snippt option("dbtable", "[1test]")  it will read the data from SQLSERVER and dont forget to accept answer if its solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: It works, it wasn't the actual drivers, it was the square brackets, thank you so much for your help :)